# Where is the USB TTY'S in masOS Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

Hi I go to the `/dev` folder and I see this:

```
afsc_type5          ptyw7
auditpipe           ptyw8
auditsessions           ptyw9
autofs              ptywa
autofs_control          ptywb
autofs_homedirmounter       ptywc
autofs_notrigger        ptywd
autofs_nowait           ptywe
bpf0                ptywf
bpf1                random
bpf2                rdisk0
bpf3                rdisk0s1
bpf4                rdisk0s2
console             rdisk0s3
cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port  rdisk1
disk0               sdt
disk0s1             stderr
disk0s2             stdin
disk0s3             stdout
disk1               systrace
dtrace              tty
dtracehelper            tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
fbt             ttyp0
fd              ttyp1
fsevents            ttyp2
io8log              ttyp3
io8logmt            ttyp4
io8logtemp          ttyp5
lockstat            ttyp6
machtrace           ttyp7
null                ttyp8
oslog               ttyp9
oslog_stream            ttypa
pf              ttypb
pfm             ttypc
pmCPU               ttypd
profile             ttype
ptmx                ttypf
ptyp0               ttyq0
ptyp1               ttyq1
ptyp2               ttyq2
ptyp3               ttyq3
ptyp4               ttyq4
ptyp5               ttyq5
ptyp6               ttyq6
ptyp7               ttyq7
ptyp8               ttyq8
ptyp9               ttyq9
ptypa               ttyqa
ptypb               ttyqb
ptypc               ttyqc
ptypd               ttyqd
ptype               ttyqe
ptypf               ttyqf
ptyq0               ttyr0
ptyq1               ttyr1
ptyq2               ttyr2
ptyq3               ttyr3
ptyq4               ttyr4
ptyq5               ttyr5
ptyq6               ttyr6
ptyq7               ttyr7
ptyq8               ttyr8
ptyq9               ttyr9
ptyqa               ttyra
ptyqb               ttyrb
ptyqc               ttyrc
ptyqd               ttyrd
ptyqe               ttyre
ptyqf               ttyrf
ptyr0               ttys0
ptyr1               ttys000
ptyr2               ttys1
ptyr3               ttys2
ptyr4               ttys3
ptyr5               ttys4
ptyr6               ttys5
ptyr7               ttys6
ptyr8               ttys7
ptyr9               ttys8
ptyra               ttys9
ptyrb               ttysa
ptyrc               ttysb
ptyrd               ttysc
ptyre               ttysd
ptyrf               ttyse
ptys0               ttysf
ptys1               ttyt0
ptys2               ttyt1
ptys3               ttyt2
ptys4               ttyt3
ptys5               ttyt4
ptys6               ttyt5
ptys7               ttyt6
ptys8               ttyt7
ptys9               ttyt8
ptysa               ttyt9
ptysb               ttyta
ptysc               ttytb
ptysd               ttytc
ptyse               ttytd
ptysf               ttyte
ptyt0               ttytf
ptyt1               ttyu0
ptyt2               ttyu1
ptyt3               ttyu2
ptyt4               ttyu3
ptyt5               ttyu4
ptyt6               ttyu5
ptyt7               ttyu6
ptyt8               ttyu7
ptyt9               ttyu8
ptyta               ttyu9
ptytb               ttyua
ptytc               ttyub
ptytd               ttyuc
ptyte               ttyud
ptytf               ttyue
ptyu0               ttyuf
ptyu1               ttyv0
ptyu2               ttyv1
ptyu3               ttyv2
ptyu4               ttyv3
ptyu5               ttyv4
ptyu6               ttyv5
ptyu7               ttyv6
ptyu8               ttyv7
ptyu9               ttyv8
ptyua               ttyv9
ptyub               ttyva
ptyuc               ttyvb
ptyud               ttyvc
ptyue               ttyvd
ptyuf               ttyve
ptyv0               ttyvf
ptyv1               ttyw0
ptyv2               ttyw1
ptyv3               ttyw2
ptyv4               ttyw3
ptyv5               ttyw4
ptyv6               ttyw5
ptyv7               ttyw6
ptyv8               ttyw7
ptyv9               ttyw8
ptyva               ttyw9
ptyvb               ttywa
ptyvc               ttywb
ptyvd               ttywc
ptyve               ttywd
ptyvf               ttywe
ptyw0               ttywf
ptyw1               urandom
ptyw2               vboxdrv
ptyw3               vboxdrvu
ptyw4               vboxnetctl
ptyw5               zero
ptyw6
```

But I search for some like `ttyUSB0` (like linux)

PD:

```
macOs Sierra V10.12.4 (16E195)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
```

Answer (score 4):

[Apple doesn't configure a tty for USB ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784248/mac-os-analog-to-dev-ttyusbxx) without a connected adapter. It's up to the hardware you connect to either have drivers or expose the drivers Apple has shipped.

The venerable [Keyspan USA-19HS has been my weapon of choice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000VYJRY) for serial to USB needs since before this web site was born.